# How do I update a kernel mode driver certificate?

Tags: kernel, driver, code-signing-certificate

I am wondering when my current kernel mode driver signing certificate expires, (which has been through the MS process) do I need to resubmit it through Microsoft's driver signing process, or can I just resign and send it out?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate? like which signing certificate you were using? 

If your certificate expires then  you have to get it cross signed by MS again.

Comment: it's an EV certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more on the MS site... you have to sign it with new EV certificate, then resubmit driver on MS site.